# How to genericize this parse rule to include any verbs for this UML Dialect?

Tags: parsing, uml, rebol

I want to make a PARSE rule (`use-rule`) for including several verbs: **Connect**, **Use**, **List**, **Show**, etc.

```
use-rule: [
     some [
        copy Actor to 'Connect
        thru 'Connect 'to
        copy UseCase to end (
             append output rejoin ["[" Actor "]-(" "Connect to " UseCase ")"]
        )
     ]
|
    [
        copy Actor to 'Use 
        thru 'Use 
        copy UseCase to end (
            append output rejoin ["[" Actor "]-(" "Use " UseCase ")"]
        )
    ]
|
    [
         copy Actor to 'List
         thru 'List 
         copy UseCase to end (
             append output rejoin ["[" Actor "]-(" "List " UseCase ")"]
         )
    ]
|

;; ...
;; same for Show, Search, Select, Checkout, Pay, Delete, Modify, Add, Manage
;; ...

]
```

How can I make it generic, so it accepts any verbs?  Something like:

```
[
    copy Actor to 'Any-Verb
    thru 'Any-Verb copy UseCase to end (
        append output rejoin ["[" Actor "]-(" "Any-Verb " UseCase ")"]
    )
]
```

This way I'd not need to add a new section to the rule each time I need a new verb?

*(Note: That rule is part of a global parse rule used here http://askuml.com/blog/e-commerce/)*

Answer (score 0):

Rather than do that I'd prefer to write a function that takes all the verbs as the input and to generate the parse rule for you.  So, if there's a new verb, you just add it to the list of verbs rather than modify the rule.  And that would avoid errors too ... is your 2nd to last parse rule an error?

Comment: that is not generic enough for me I want to make it work for any verb that I don't know in advance :)

Comment: is your 2nd to last parse rule an error? I don't understand what you mean ?

Comment: 'copy Actor to 'Add thru 'Connect 'to copy UseCase to end (append output ... ' which differs from every other rule you have.

Comment: Sounds you like you want to parse by position instead then. If verb is always a single word without spaces, you can just parse by spaces instead.  Of course it helps if you actually provide some sample data or describe the rules your data follows.